# Serialize array with strong_parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am trying to save a array using the strong_parameters gem. But I am having issues with how the form is sending my array. The params look like this:

```
> params[:circuit] 
=> {"title"=>"Some title", ..., "viewable_tasks"=>{"0"=>"woop", "1"=>"dee", ...}}
```

And my `circuit_params` function looks like:

```
def circuit_params
  params.require(:circuit).permit(:title, :id, viewable_tasks: { }, ... )
end
```

I can't seem to get the syntax to allow my params to work. What I get in my console is:

```
> circuit_params
=> {"title"=>"implement plug-and-play mindshare",
 "viewable_tasks"=>{"0"=>nil, "1"=>nil, "2"=>nil}, ...
```

In my model I have:

```
class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :viewable_tasks, Array
   ...
end
```

I noticed that I can get it to work properly with attributes I call `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on, so this may have something to do with it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had the same issue and this was the correct syntax:

```
def circuit_params
  params.require(:circuit).permit(:title, :id, {:viewable_tasks => []}, ... )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the serialized items must be in the end of the permit parameters. In my experience (and i dont know exactly why), you cannot input another unserialized item after a serialized one... try and let us know.

Comment: It's because of Ruby syntax. It's not a Rails restriction. Ruby allows a hash to be at the end of a parameter list without enclosing it in {braces}. If a hash is not at the end, it must be in braces.

Comment: I'm not sure why, @Hamdan. The ability to leave the braces off a hash at the end is probably for convenience and readability and to encourage a convention of a hash being the last param. In the Rails `permit` method, BTW, you totally can put a hash in the beginning or middle of the list if you use the braces.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
def circuit_params
  params.require(:circuit).permit(:title, :id, viewable_tasks:[], ... )
end
```

Comment: As I said, the hashes need to necessarily be at the end of the permit parameters