# Problems saving a two dimensional array in Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two dimensional array that contains lat and lng data from a user's run log. Array can contain numerous elements in it. 
For example:

```
    rundata = [[40.7174141, -74.0015233], [40.7174141, -54.0015233], 
    [20.7174141, -74.0015233]]
```

I need to save this to the db. Here is what my controller looks like with strong params:

```
    class TrackrunsController < ApiController
       before_action :require_login, except: [:index, :show]

     def create
        trackrun = Trackrun.create!(trackruns_params)
        trackrun.user = current_user    
        if trackrun.save
            render json: {
              message: 'ok',
              trackrun: trackrun,
          }
        else
          render json: {message: 'Could not create run'}
     end

      private
      def trackruns_params
         params.require(:trackrun).permit(:rundata)
      end

  end
```

My Model for trackrun:

```
  class Trackrun < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    serialize :rundata

  end
```

Keep getting an error for Unpremiited params in my console.

Any ideas what might be wrong.

error:

```
    Processing by TrackrunsController#create as HTML
    09:34:03 api.1  |   Parameters: {"trackrun"=>{"rundata"=>
    [[40.7174141, -74.0015233]]}}
    09:34:03 api.1  |   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM 
    "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["auth_token", 
    "2H8CzejjWK2SD3KhfZDgq6tc"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    09:34:03 api.1  | Unpermitted parameter: :rundata
    09:34:03 api.1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    09:34:03 api.1  |   SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "trackruns" 
    ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  
    [["created_at", "2017-10-13 13:34:03.072208"], ["updated_at", 
    "2017-10-13 13:34:03.072208"]]
    09:34:03 api.1  |    (1.2ms)  COMMIT
    09:34:03 api.1  |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM 
    "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["auth_token", 
    "2H8CzejjWK2SD3KhfZDgq6tc"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    09:34:03 api.1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    09:34:03 api.1  |   SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "trackruns" SET 
    "updated_at" = $1, "user_id" = $2 WHERE "trackruns"."id" = $3  
    [["updated_at", "2017-10-13 13:34:03.084035"], ["user_id", 1], 
    ["id", 27]]
    09:34:03 api.1  |    (1.2ms)  COMMIT
    09:34:03 api.1  | Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 0.6ms | 
    ActiveRecord: 13.2ms)
```

UPDATE:

this is the request from the frontend...

```
handleStopRun () {
const entireRun = [...this.state.runData]
console.log('from stop run', entireRun)
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.state.runID);
this.setState({ runID: null }) 
axios('/trackruns', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Token ${Auth.getToken()}`,
    token: Auth.getToken(),
  },
  data: {
    trackrun: {
      // rundata is the two dimensional array being passed to rails
      rundata: this.state.runData,
    }
  },
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
  this.setState({
    shouldFireRedirect: true,
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

}

ANOTHER UPDATE: Made some changes that are listed below. Getting another error now

Controller:

```
def create
    trackrun = Trackrun.new
    trackrun.rundata = trackruns_params
    trackrun.user = current_user
    trackrun.save
    render json: { trackrun: trackrun }
end

private
def trackruns_params
    a = params.require(:trackrun).permit(:rundata=>[])
    a
end
```

MODEL:

```
class Trackrun < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user, optional: true
   serialize :rundata, Array

end
```

ERROR: Tring to debugg since yesterday with no luck, Please help!

```
 Started POST "/trackruns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-14 10:56:18 -0400
 10:56:18 api.1  | Processing by TrackrunsController#create as HTML
 10:56:18 api.1  |   Parameters: {"trackrun"=>{"rundata"=>[[40.7174796, 
    -74.0013829]]}}
 10:56:18 api.1  |   User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" 
  WHERE "users"."auth_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["auth_token", 
 "RKs5Z8h21aYanGTmGgxMnDry"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 10:56:18 api.1  | Unpermitted parameter: :rundata
 10:56:18 api.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms 
 (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
 10:56:18 api.1  |
 10:56:18 api.1  |
 10:56:18 api.1  |
 10:56:18 api.1  | ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch (can't 
 serialize 
`rundata`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a 
ActionController::Parameters. -- <ActionController::Parameters {} 
permitted: true>):
10:56:18 api.1  |
10:56:18 api.1  | app/controllers/trackruns_controller.rb:12:in 
`create'
```

Comment: I see `Unpermitted parameter: :rundata` in your log. Probably you should change permit for rundata. Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983208/serialize-array-with-strong-parameters

Comment: Tried that as well. Changed my params to params.require(:trackrun).permit({:rundata => []}) Error still remains to unpermitted params

Comment: I don't believe you. `params.require(:trackrun).permit(rundata: [])` should work.

Comment: params.require(:trackrun).permit(rundata: [])  still gets an unpermitted params error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the bulk assignment. Try the following:

```
trackrun = Trackrun.new
trackrun.rundata = variable_with_the_array
trackrun.user = current_user  
if trackrun.save 
....
```

Edit after question edit and comment:
Ash, add

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

to your json request. For requests that post to TrackrunsController use also

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

and

```
data: JSON.stringify(data).
```

Comment: gives this error: NameError (undefined local variable or method `variable_with_the_array' for #<TrackrunsController:0x007fe4e9957a38>):

Comment: variable_with_the_array is meant to be a placeholder that you should change to whatever the variable holds the array you are trying to save. (ex. rundata)

Comment: this is the error now:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "--- []

Comment: so this works in the rail console and it saves the data:  Trackrun.create!({:rundata => [[2323,2323], [232, 4545]]}) . i think the problem is definitely in my strong params

Comment: What variable and what does contain when you pass when you get PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: malformed array literal:?  Calling create and then save should be consolidated, otherwise 'could not create the run' is more a 'user could not be associated to the run'

Comment: passing in :rundata and it contains the 2 dimensional array. I also updated my original post to show the frontend request

Comment: I haven't recreated your code but I think the params are not passing what you think.  try changing the second line to   trackrun.rundata = [[40.7174141, -74.0015233], [40.7174141, -54.0015233], 
    [20.7174141, -74.0015233]]  .

Comment: Your suggestion works if i REMOVE the serialize line from my MODEL. If i leave the serialize line then i get this ERROR:  malformed array literal: "--- [] which is very ODD to me. On the other hand I am thinking as you are, that the params are not passing in what they are suppose to. This is really slowing me down as i need to get moving from this project quick. Any other suggestions?

Comment: hmm.....I was under the impression that AXIOS already uses JSON when sending requests so why do we need to explicitly state that.  Also are you suggesting the following for stringify:  ( please see my update in your answer )

Comment: data: {
    trackrun: {
      rundata: JSON.stringify(entireRun)
    }
  },   ( is this what you are suggesting? )

Comment: yes. I edited the answer to avoid a long change but the edits were rejected.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. Thanks for all of your help. Greatly appreciated! However, in my case i ended up using a JSONB to save the array in rails db and it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you whitelist an array, you have to explicity specify it's an array.

```
  def trackruns_params
     params.require(:trackrun).permit(rundata: [])
  end
```

Comment: This doesn't work since run_data is the multidimensional array.