# Association integration in a REST API with Rails and Angular 2/4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, rest

I'm working in a web application with Angular 2/4 on client side and a Rails application on the server side. In the rails side I have a model `Product` that has the following serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :weight
    belongs_to :brand
end
```

This serializer generates:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "weight": 62.0,
    "brand": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo"
    }
}
```

Then, in Angular I have this class to parse the JSON:

```
export class Produto implements Model {
    id: number;
    weight: number;
    brand: Brand;
}
```

Until here is everything ok, the issue began when the user alter the `Product` and the Angular has to send the `Product` altered to update route in Rails. If I just send the TypeScript object in the body of `PUT` or `POST`, the generated JSON will have the same pattern that the one received from Rails. But my rails app was expecting the following pattern:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "weight": 62.0,
    "brand_id": 1
}
```

In the `ProductController` I have the method `product_params` that I did this workaround to accept the pattern sended by Angular:

```
def produto_params
    params[:brand_id] = params[:brand][:id] if params[:brand][:id]
    params.delete(:brand) if params[:brand]
    params.permit(:weight, :brand_id)
end
```

All said, this looks ugly and not scalable at all. This is just one association, if my product scale to 5 association this will grow big. Besides that, I can have many others situations like that with others models.

I think that I'm doing structure wrong, but where is wrong and where is right is obscure to me, so I need some help to structure in a scalable way.

Some considerations: Both Angular app and Rails app are mine and they are in early development, so I can do structural changes with few troubles. I learning Ruby, Rails, TypeScript and Angular with this project, but I'm trying to reuse code the maximum I can, so what want to achieve is a structure that I don't need to write serializer for every model in both sides. A approach that thought was a generic serializer in Angular, using decoratos in the fields that carry object from association, so overriding the `toJSON()` method I would transform a `brand` in a `brand_id` (don't know if is even possible), this would be a bad approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have to use a Serializer, the natural fix for the issue is to add a corresponding Deserializer, right? OR don't transform the object with any serialization in the first place, just pass the normal model object back and forth.

Comment: did you look requiring nested attributes like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604493/3307520. Nevertheless, good question.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko agreed, but if I already have a serializer which knows how to parse my model to JSON looks strange I have to implement another class to do the way back, right? If exist a way to use the same class that serialize to deserialize would be great. And the other option, just send the data without serialize, yeah I could do that, but I think it would be problematic when the response has many registers, so to get the informations like brand for example, I would need to do many requisitions.

Comment: @Cyzanfar I saw this, but I think that require nested attributes blocks the possibility to update the association.